# Efficiently Concatenate Pandas DataFrames in series

Tags: python, numpy

I have 10 DataFrames with equal number of rows and each having their own set of unique columns (not shared between any dataframes). I want to simply add the dataframes together in series, such that the final dataframe contains all the columns contained in all the dataframes. The first row of the final dataframe would contain the first row of the first, followed by the first row of the second, and so on til the tenth dataframe. I have tried pandas.concat(dataframes, axis=1), but it ended up creating NaN values in my numerical data somehow. I worked around it by writing an extremely slow and ugly method that increments through the rows by index and creating row by row the final data frame. What is the correct pandas way to do this?

Comment: it is because row count of DataFrames are different. Can you show me the shape of DataFrames?

Comment: You need to have all data frames reindexed to be the same, and then call `pd.merge` or `pd.concat`.

Comment: @Wonjin no, as I said they all have the same number of rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming all your dataframes are in a list `df_list`:

```
df0_index = df_list[0].index # get the first data frame's index

for i in range(1, len(df_list)):
    df_list[i] = df_list[i].set_index(df0_index) # reindex all the other dataframes

df_out = pd.concat(df_list, axis=1) # concatenate
```

Comment: I wish I'd of known this 8 hours ago!  I need to take time to better understand Index's. Thank you.

Comment: Hey, sorry, I actually tried this out, and it doesn't work. I'm still inexplicably obtaining NaN values. It's pretty mind boggling to me at this point, I think the problem is with Pandas and not my code.

Comment: @YungGun it's unfortunate you unaccepted... if the problem is with pandas. Anyway I'll try to create an example some time.

Comment: @YungGun I tried it. I understand why the issue occurs, but `set_index` works, so you can try that.

Answer (score 2):

You could do this with list comprehension:

```
pd.concat([df.reset_index(drop=True) for df in df_list], axis = 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Got it working. Simply had to set "ignore_index" to true when calling pandas.concat().

```
pd.concat(df_list, axis=1, ignore_index=True) # returns dataframes correctly.
```

Note that reindexing wouldn't work for some reason.